# How do partial- and full flaps compare for gusty approaches?

Tags: aerodynamics, landing, approach, flaps, aircraft-operations

From an aerodynamic aspect, how do partial flaps and full flaps compare for gusty approaches?

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: How do you rate what’s best? Best in what sense?

Comment: What kind of airplane are you talking about?  The answer would likely be different if you were talking about a B757 versus a Cessna 150.

Comment: I fly my archer with 2 notches instead of 3 on gusty days. I yank the last notch in on short final, I find it helps with the yawing a bit. Maybe add 5 knots to my approach speed as well.

Comment: My question is mainly in general as the aerodynamic principal will remain the same for all fixed wing aircrafts.

Comment: I can't provide a full answer, but I do know that a good part of the benefits of flying with less than full flaps is that you are then required to fly at a faster airspeed, which increases the effectiveness of your control surfaces and you are better able to respond to the gusts.

Comment: FWIW, for 747-100/200 aircraft at the two carriers I worked for, all landings were done at 30 degree flaps regardless of the approach conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure when it comes to large aircraft, but when you select partial flaps or opt for a no-flap approach and landing, it results in a higher speed on approach and landing.

If you then break down the wind components in vectors, the cross-wind component becomes relatively smaller, so it is as if you have less cross-wind and don’t need to have such a large cross-track angle upon landing (less crab) or less cross-control when touching down. Even though the effect is small, it is noticeable.

You can compare it with a small single-engine piston trying to stay on course with 30° of crosswind at 100 kts needing perhaps 15-25° of cross-track angle while a fighter flying at 450 kts only needs 3-5° or so under the same conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It varies from airframe to airframe, though often times OEMs recommend partial flaps and a gust factor be added to Vref in order to ensure positive control all the way through the approach and roundout - at least for light aircraft.